# R: "Error calling capture_console_output: 87" when using terminalExecute()

Tags: r, terminal

I am trying to run an executable called swat_edit.exe in R. It works perfectly when I run it directly in the command prompt, and also when I run it directly in the Terminal tab in R. However, when I try to write a function in R to run the executable, I get an error (I get a number of different errors...).

I have tried to use different methods of running the file:

1: I used system("swat_edit"), which returns the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.Console.set_CursorVisible(Boolean value)
   at SWEdit.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at SWEdit.Program.Main(String[] args)
[1] 17234
```

2: I used shell("swat_edit"), which returns the exact same error as (1).

3: I used shell.exec("swat_edit"). This works, but it opens the executable in a new window, which then runs for a few seconds and closes (as intended). I need the program to run in the R terminal window so it can run many iterations in the background without disrupting other things. This is not a viable option.

4: I tried using terminalSend(ID,"swat_edit") (from the rstudioapi package). This works in that it sends the command to the terminal window in R. When I move there and hit enter it executes perfectly, running in the terminal window like I want it to. However, I need to run many iterations so this is not viable either. I tried using KeyboardSimulator to go to the Terminal tab and hitting enter (which worked), but this also does not let me use the PC for other purposes while running my code.

5: I tried using terminalExecute("swat_edit"), which returns the following error code:

```
Error calling capture_console_output: 87
[Process completed]
[Exit code: -532462766]
```

6: I tried making a python file that runs swat_edit.exe, and then running that file in R. The python file works when I run it by itself, from the command prompt, or from the terminal in R. It does not, however, work when I try to run it in the R terminal using terminalExecute (same error as in (5)).

NOTE: I have another executable called swat.exe (entirely different program) that works with all of the above-mentioned methods.

So in summary: swat_edit.exe runs perfectly in command prompt and R terminal, but does not work when I try to run it using R code (either system(), shell(), or terminalExecute().

I can't figure out the difference between terminalExecute() and typing the string into terminal and hitting enter, but apparently there is something happening in between...

It will be tedious to reproduce this since it uses external programs, but if anyone has any idea about the error messages or how I can copy a string and run it in the terminal without any interference, that would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I found a method that solves my problem. I created a .bat file that runs swat_edit minimized. I was able to run this .bat file with the shell function (or any of the other commands I mentioned) in R. This doesn't answer why I was having the issues I described, and it doesn't let me run swat_edit in the R terminal, but it's good enough for me.

The .bat file was simply the following:
"START /MIN /WAIT C:\~\SWAT_Edit.exe"